# Xubuntu 14.10; How to do an ISO Installation directly from an internal hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, 14.10, iso

My little brother's laptop is a terrible computer and is currently crapping out on its use of Windows 7. I don't have any USB drives or disks and I don't know how to make a LiveCD anyways. I just really need to figure out how to install Xubuntu 14.10 directly onto a computer using Windows 7 currently through its internal hard drive. Help me, please.

Comment: You used to be able install Ubuntu from Windows using a tool called Wubi, but this is no longer available.

Comment: It is possible to install Ubuntu [over the network using PXE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) but you'd have to setup and configure a DHCP and TFTP server and their isn't an Xubuntu netboot image so you'd have to install Ubuntu and convert it to Xubuntu after the installation which probably isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Uninstall all Windows applications.

Run the scandisk and defrag.

Download the Xubuntu iso file: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/xubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

Reduce Windows partition on everything possible and leave unpartitioned space.

Download and install EasyBCD for personal, non-commercial use: https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Open EasyBCD and click `Add New Entry` from the left side.

Then on the bottom, select `ISO Boot` and then find the ISO file you want to boot from.

Then give it a name, click `Add Entry` and then Restart.

There should be an option, when you boot,to boot from the entry you just made.

Boot from Iso and install Xubuntu in the unpartitioned space, with manual partitioning, at least three partitions, one primary ext4 for /, a logical ext4 / home and logic, swap system. The Grub in the MBR of /dev/sda.